# Docker Container Azure WebAPP Flask error while deploying due to port

Tags: azure, docker, flask

I have implemented a Flask APP with python and by using Docker Desktop I have obtained an image of my APP. I pushed that app on my private docker HUB. In the Azure portal I have created a docker container based APP service including user, password.

The dockerized APP works perfectly on my laptop with this dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.3
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip \
python3-dev \
build-essential \
cmake
ADD . /demo
WORKDIR /demo
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE  80 5000
```

here the docker-composer.yml

```
 version: "3.8"
 services:
 app:
  build: .
   command: python app.py
 ports:
  - "5000:5000"
 volumes:
   - .:/demo
```

here a little part of app.py

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

As said with these files the docker works on my laptop, but during the deploying stage in azure I received the following error:

```
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
INFO - Initiating warmup request to container xxx for site xxx
ERROR - Container xxx for site xxx has exited, failing site start
 ERROR - Container xxx didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
 INFO - Stopping site xxx because it failed during startup.
```

Comment: In docker-compose.yml file try changing port mapping like `ports:
  - "80:5000"`. I assume that on your laptop you are able to run the app using `locahost:5000`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood, by using ports: "5000:5000" I was able to run the app, while now using "80:5000" the app goes in conflict, I think, with other applications on my laptop. Now, I'm trying to push the app on Azure with your change.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood, even including "80:5000" it returns the same errors as in the post.

Comment: Try changing the app.run line of code to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)` in app.py

Comment: Finally, deployed. the docker file should contain only 5000, and before the deployment in Azure Web APP we must set the port variable to 5000 (i.e, PORT=5000).